Testing WS2811 Soldering Safely
I am working on a project that requires me to solder many WS2811 lights in series (with a ground, data and power wire).
When wiring these up, I am concerned that once power is delivered to the light, if any of the wires are crossed (and the 5v wire touches the data wire), it will deliver power back to the RPi and fry everything.
I am curious if this concern is warranted, and if so how I can test that the lights work safely (I do not mind frying a few of the lights, just not the RPi). I've attached a photo of my (rookie) soldering and a diagram to explain what I mean.
For this project I will have to solder a few hundred of these, so want to make sure I don't get most of the way through and fry everything!
Thanks in advance.



The Raspberry Pi is a 3.3v device but those LEDs expect 5v signals, so you should use a 3.3v compatible 5v buffer in between the Pi and the LEDs. If you short something to data you'll probably damage that cheap buffer and not the Pi.

Your schematic shows +5V connected to the first WS2811, but doesn't show how its return is connected to GND. That GND connection must be tied to Rpi's GND as well. This GND connection is critical for the high currents flowing in such a long string of 100.

To get better connections, you need to tin the wires before soldering them to the little boards. That way, you can trim the ends with flush cutters and you won't get the wispy bits of wire that could cause short circuits—very noticeable in the bottom of the photo.

what @AndrewMorton said and use heatshrink tubing

you could also place the LEDs into final position, run two bus bar wires for power next to the LEDs , then use thinner wire to connect the LEDs to the bus bar wires

I like @jsotola idea. The wires in the photo are too thick for the pads on the WS2811  PCBs. Run continuous +5 and Gnd wires and tap them with thinner wires that connect +5 and Gnd at diagonal opposite ends of the PCBs to reduce crowding. Use flux and less solder so there aren't "bumps" of solder in the finished joint.

Does "WS2811" mean there's a LED driver IC per board and you get addressable LEDs? It appears to be the name of a LED driver IC but I see no IC on the pics, it's located on the other side?

@jsotola In this specific case, shrink tube won't do any good if the soldering was done proper.

You can buy WS2811 (and similar) ICs with LEDs pre-assembled into LED strip (example). You should consider if any of those are suitable for your requirements rather than having to solder several hundred LED modules yourself. Whichever approach you take note Mark Leavitt's suggestion of running thicker power wires and tapping them in at points along your run.

Regarding the soldering part of the question: these joints were poorly soldered. Some are cold joints and you have peeled the wrong amount of insulation on pretty much every wire. The wires are also attached incorrectly, they should be completely straight at the place where the joint is formed.
As a result you will get oxidation over time and the joints will not handle mechanical stress at all. Remove them and clean up the pads with solder wick.
Doing this proper is harder than one might think at a glance, so don't be too disheartened if you are a beginner at soldering. The way to do this proper is as follows:

Measure the pad length with a ruler/calipers and then preferably use a wire stripper tool where you can adjust the peel length accordingly. Peel for the whole length of the pad, no more no less. The insulation should begin at the edge of the PCB. Check that no strands were damaged during peeling.
After peeling, carefully gather the strands with your fingers - do not twist them needlessly but let them follow the natural twist of the cable. Do not bend the wire in any direction. Cut it at the appropriate length. In this case it looks like you need to peel it in both ends. Obviously there shouldn't be an open cut in the middle of the cable like in the picture.
Carefully pre-apply solder on the peeled wire. Doing this is pretty hard as you easily melt the insulation or cause it to travel up the wire. You may want to turn the solder iron heat down a bit if you are struggling with this.
Pre-apply solder on the pads as well, just a tiny bit to ensure there's wetting and no oxidation (in this case you'll already have solder residue there so it won't be a problem and you can skip this).
Ideally fix the wire mechanically on top of the pad before soldering, so it won't move. You can use tape or a fixture etc. The wire should be completely straight against the pad and no air gap.
Use a chisel tip and touch the pad first, then move it in against the side of the peeled wire. You can add a little bit of extra solder at this point to help the wetting.

Also note that LEDs in particular are sensitive components that don't really like getting soldered multiple times over, so the boards could already be damaged. You've also butchered one of the LEDs with the solder tip so that LED needs replacement - if it isn't already broken now, it may break after some time.
